# How to properly use satisfies

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, tsx

I'm building a custom React hook using latest TypeScript. I have issues understanding how to properly use `satisfies` operator. The reason why I want to use it is because I'm unable to pass conditional values.

My Hook:

```
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
import { axiosClient } from '@src/features/@Api';
import type {
  FeathersFind,
  FeathersQuery,
} from '@features/@Api/@types/feathers';
import type { Model } from '@features/@Api/@types/models';

type Result = FeathersFind & {
  data: Model[];
};

type Query = FeathersQuery & Model;

export const useFetchModels = (query?: Query) => {
  const defaultQuery = {
    $limit: 1000,
    $sort: {
      createdAt: -1,
    },
    ...(query || {}),
  };
  const { isFetching, isLoading, refetch, data, ...rest } = useQuery(
    'query-models',
    async () => {
      const { data }: { data: Result } = await axiosClient.get('/models', {
        params: defaultQuery,
      });
      return data;
    },
    {
      cacheTime: 1000 * 60 * 60,
    }
  );
  return { isFetching, isLoading, refetch, data, ...rest };
};
```

How I use it

```
  const [selectedMakeId, setSelectedMakeId] = React.useState('imagine-valid-id-here');
  const { data: models } = useFetchModels({
    makeId: selectedMakeId,
  });
```

The error:

> ```
> Argument of type '{ makeId: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Query | undefined'.
>  Type '{ makeId: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Model': _id, name, make, createdAt, updatedAt
> ```

The types: (tried  FeathersQuery | Model; and  FeathersQuery & Model;)

```
type Query = FeathersQuery | Model;
export type FeathersQuery = {
  $limit?: number;
  $skip?: number;
  $sort?: {
    [key: string]: 1 | -1;
  };
};
export type Model = {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
  make: Make;
  makeId: string;
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date;
};
```

End goal:
I want to conditionally be able to pass ANY of the values from both objects. I'm guessing I need to use new operator satisfied for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code lacks a few types so it's hard to be 100% sure of the intent.

Assuming the intent is to pass in any field of `Model` to us it as a filter in the `useFetchModels` hook, then what you are actually looking for is `Partial`. This will allow you to specify any property present on `Model`  but will not require you to specify all the required properties of `Model` (it makes all properties of the passed in type optional)

```
type Query = FeathersQuery & Partial<Model>;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMCKz1QJ5wC+cAZlBCHAORToCGAxjALQCOO+VA3AFCiSw4AJXpNS5SjVEwqPGHjDo4AMXowAFrlTLgAOwAmcALyJCchUoCydANZKTCM-MXD0qZABt4J1XQ1adAzgAMkQeODh9PzoALjhLCH10DwBtAF1eQl4edAAPAXhnJV9-KFRsXAIHcLgAEg9QYBgAfjjdZBAAI1xeCNrUG2AwVrh2rp6a-ugWuIQaiJS7PDjUGCg9AHM0uIBGOAAfOGYd3qJM3jyCuCL4xOTjMIiAfWB9FbXN0906EHR39d0G1OIFsf3ioOBoIAkm84KsAUCagxaH50PoAIIwOIAEVRp2QYCiMDRmJxeJ4WR45hcFXwDxKmjKtIIoQACnRYMA6B4ADwJJIeAB82Uu0zgDAgulWKAwqhgDHU-OSqAeAAp2JURsyAJTGQWPcWS6VJEh0TwwZkPOYRPoNEBNXYABmdABp5nVUNNZu6Isi1CSsUcdm6bUQQzaAHRR9UcAj7Q6ObXhym+o3wJDAbToeXqTYuuCZgAyEDo+jzcFoJGzCvzRLo+ajEdo0uIJjQWFjqvdVA1+GYIDuHlQVHDEToqDwugYcFVuqM+utocNUvTkWiRFma5gsVc7i8RAe7Q8HgAhD6K9nkFBdFu6KcIoRRwbQwxGJoACqgME7Z2OuAAKjgAA2P9AJAp8zAibVTloGArxvDMsxzcsixLMtAXzStq3UWtogbKNm3gSlKSpCUVzgFIMA8dAmDRaw7BhfMMBgABlZIaOJfR6PQGE0geERGBgCN2xY7diVVKhQDoDY9HQZgADduVeZhlMZdAqGgngyOlJA6ziAcBRVVsZXQOUFSVIdVUXEEGNhKiOLo6F9DdQhoKAA)